# Why "CWinApp::InitInstance()" called in "MyApp InitInstance()" without error？

Tags: function, visual-c++, mfc

The `InitInstance()` in `CWinApp` is a `virtual` function, I think it should be reported "undefined reference" error here, but nothing happens. So, I want to know why and the reason to put it here. Thanks in advance. Below code is generated automatically by Visual Studio 2022 for MFC App.

```
BOOL CSaleSystemApp::InitInstance()
{
    // InitCommonControlsEx() is required on Windows XP if an application
    // manifest specifies use of ComCtl32.dll version 6 or later to enable
    // visual styles.  Otherwise, any window creation will fail.
    INITCOMMONCONTROLSEX InitCtrls;
    InitCtrls.dwSize = sizeof(InitCtrls);
    // Set this to include all the common control classes you want to use
    // in your application.
    InitCtrls.dwICC = ICC_WIN95_CLASSES;
    InitCommonControlsEx(&InitCtrls);

    // login first
    loginDlg = new CMyLoginDialog();
    loginDlg->DoModal();

    CWinApp::InitInstance();  <--- it's a virtual function in CWinApp, why called here?
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Correct, [`CWinApp::InitInstance`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/cwinapp-class#initinstance) is a `virtual` function.

The expression `CWinApp::InitInstance()`, however, de-virtualizes the function call, delegating it to the implementation provided by `CWinApp` (or one of its base classes in case `CWinApp` doesn't implement it [which it does]).

This may seem awkward, but the awkward thing really is, that C++' inheritance model only caters to "true" specialization. It doesn't provide for a way to express "partial specialization", where the derived class and the base class coöperate; it's either the derived class' or base class' virtual function that executes. C++ doesn't allow you to do "special" things in the derived class **in addition to** the common things provided by the base<sup>1</sup>.

`<base class>::<virtual function>(...)` instructs the compiler to emit a function call to the `base class`' implementation of `virtual function`. In case of `CWinApp::InitInstance()` that function is known to both the compiler and linker, so both the compiler and linker are happy.

---

<sup>1</sup> *Though that really is a consequence that we've stopped using `class`es for what they are meant for. It is ultimately a violation of the [Rule of zero](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three#Rule_of_zero).*

Comment: Thanks guy, but it's hard for me to understand what you say, would you pls provide more detail explanation or give the learning path to understand it?

Comment: It's basically [this](https://godbolt.org/z/Mr8cv3v1a). You'll need to understand [derived classes](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/derived_class) and [virtual functions](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/virtual). And scope resolution. Each one is an involved topic in itself.

Comment: That said, there's **absolutely** no requirement for you to accept an answer that doesn't explain things in a way you can easily comprehend.

Comment: I went through link you provide and understand it. but CWinApp::InitInstance() is empty and also its parent(CWinThread) and parent's parent(CCmdTarge) are also empty.(the root parent is CObject, but no InitInstance() found there) so why can compiler happy with empty?

Comment: I got it, my testing code just use "virtual void test();" so it always has compile error: undefined reference. Thanks a lot!

Comment: The compiler is always happy, as long as it finds a declaration. It's the linker that requires a definition. `CWinApp::InitInstance` is defined in *appcore.cpp*, probably exposed to the linker by way of one of the *[n|u]afxcw[d].lib* import libraries.

Comment: yes you're right, compiler always happy but linker cause error for virtual function defined like "virtual void test();" without implementation even empty implement.